# Convert .dta-file to .csv-file

Tags: c#, python, vb.net, csv

I'm currently stuck with a very rare answered question:
I have a *.dta*-file on my computer which contains different data. A normal text editor can't read it as it is binary.

To work with this file, I need to convert it to a *.csv*-file. I've made my way through Google-results, but I just get info about R and Python, nothing about VB.NET/C#.

Is there any way to convert a *.dta* file to a *.csv* in .NET?
I can't really give more information as that is all I can say about it (never worked with .dta before).

As Google does not give me any real help to that, I bring my question up here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did the .dta file come from?  Do you know what program generated it?  Or a program that uses it?  Just saying that it is a .dta file really means nothing, since it depends on who generated it in the first place.  A quick search sent me to several articles talking about possible programs that use that file extension which has nothing to do with its actual encoding.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I got the .dta-file from a guy that I should write a small thing for. I think it was generated by Stata, but I can't 100% prove this. I will ask him and respond you with the relating information. Sorry for that and thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well, he created it with Excel originally. That's what I got as information.

Comment: Try opening it with Excel.  If you can open it with Excel, then you should be able to write some C# to use the Excel api to read the data and convert it.  If not, research Stata and see if you can find the format.